# Changing DeleteBehavior.Cascade to DeleteBehavior.Restrict causes EF Core to drop foreign keys

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-2.2

ASP.NET Core 2.2 project with Entity Framework Core; I'm performing the first EF Migration to create the database:

Here are my steps:

1. I run `Add-Migration myFirstMigration` in Package Manager Console
2. I manually edit the migration files as well as `DbContextModelSnapshot.cs` to change all instances of `DeleteBehavior.Cascade` to `DeleteBehavior.Restrict` because I just want an error thrown if a row gets deleted/updated which causes a FK constraint violation
3. I run `Update-Database` which creates the database in SQL Server

Here is the part that confuses me: **If I now do `Add-Migration` again, a migration is created in which it wants to drop my Foreign Key constraints and re-add them with `DeleteBehavior.Cascade`.**

Why is it doing that? Of course it appears to have to do with setting everything to `DeleteBehavior.Restrict`, but why?

Comment: Best practice is to define the DeleteBehavior in your modelbuilder.
Fe: builder.HasOne(x => x.User).WithMany(x => x.Customers).HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

Don't change your migration files manually.